# Looking for an 'all in one' application with a script panel and a console

Tags: terminal

I'm quite impress with Windows Powershell ISE.

Here is a nice [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRdWX7yncEg).

ISE stands for 'Integrated Scripting Environment' and it's an application that has a panel at the top for scripting and a panel at the bottom with a console.

I think it's a great idea! Within the same application, it is possible to use the console as usual, but also you'd have one or multiple script panels at the top where you can write and execute scripts directly. 
Also it's possible to execute only highlighted sections of the code.

So I was thinking, how cool would it be to have something like this in my favourite Linux machine using bash!

Has anyone know about something similar for Linux?

Comment: You mean like Emacs ...?

Comment: There is also `C-x C-e` at the bash prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, emacs is always the answer :-)

I can have a script open in a buffer (in sh-mode) and a terminal in a different buffer.

Easy!